# TSMessage - Extra argument 'image' in call

Tags: swift

This sounds to be very small issue, but I am stuck :(

I am using  [TSMessage](https://github.com/toursprung/TSMessages) in swift getting error "Extra argument 'image' in call". What is wrong?

```
func showActionNotification(title:String?, message:String?, viewcontroller:UIViewController, actionTitle:NSString, action:(()->Void)) -> Void {
  var image:UIImage! = UIImage(named: "Sample.png")
  TSMessage.showNotificationInViewController(viewcontroller,
    title: title, subtitle: message, image: image,
    type: TSMessageNotificationType.Message,
    duration: TSMessageNotificationDuration.Automatic,
    callback: nil, buttonTitle: actionTitle, buttonCallback: action,
    atPosition: TSMessageNotificationPosition.Top, canBeDismissedByUser: true)
}
```

Thanks

Comment: How did you get it to work in Swift?

Comment: @ScottZhu I added bridging-header and imported the header file there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran into this same issue. The error Xcode gives is completely unrelated to what the actual problem is. It has nothing to do with the `image` argument.

It turns out, `TSMessageNotificationDuration` enums don't cast property to NSTimeInterval. I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
TSMessageNotificationDuration.Automatic as NSTimeInterval
```

Xcode complains **'TSMessageNotificationDuration' is not convertible to 'NSTimeInterval'**

So instead, I looked to see what the enums are equivalent to. In my case, I was using `TSMessageNotificationDuration.Endless`, which was equivalent to -1.

So I changed my code to the following, which worked:

```
var endless:NSTimeInterval = -1

TSMessage.showNotificationInViewController(viewController,
    title: title,
    subtitle: subtitle,
    image:image,
    type: TSMessageNotificationType.Message,
    duration: endless,
    callback: { () -> Void in },
    buttonTitle: "",
    buttonCallback: { () -> Void in },
    atPosition: TSMessageNotificationPosition.Top,
    canBeDismisedByUser: false)
```

The `TSMessageNotificationDuration.Automatic` enum is equal to 0.

I hope this helps.

Comment: You can also explicitly cast the raw value to `NSTimeInterval`: `NSTimeInterval(TSMessageNotificationDuration.Automatic.rawValue)`

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in title and message as optionals - if TSMessage (objective c?) does not want optionals that may be causing the problem.

Comment: This is not the issue, already tried that. It is not working either